# Terrain triangulation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, triangulation, terrain

I have a terrain presented by large set of points in `3D-space`. What is the best way to triangulate it?

I can just to project all points on `2D-space`, than make Delaunay triangulation in time `O(n * log(n))` and lift it back to the previous heigth. But is it good enough? I've heard about Delaunay triangulation in time `O(n * log(log(n))`) in some special cases. Is it possible in my case? Or maybe I should to use some approximation algorithm?

Comment: Delaunay on big datasets can take too much time, consider splitting on smaller rectangles...

Answer (score 2):

Projection and Delaunay triangulation in 2D is certainly a good solution which will generate well shaped triangles. For a terrain you might also need to enforce certain edges, so look for a constrained Delaunay triangulation.

As to the runtime: For real world data you can assume linear [runtime](http://www.geom.at/fade2d/html/performance.png). If performance is important, make sure your input data is not degenerate: Scanning devices often return points on a grid. You can improve the situation by adding some noise.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you did your homework OK, Delaunay triangulation is a very good solution to your problem.